# Blazor (Server-side) communicate between sibling components

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have three components.
Component one contains component two and three.
Component two is a list.
Component three is for adding items to the database.

When I have saved an item to the database I want to update the list in component two.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Scenario

Let's suppose:

```
<CRUD>
    <GRID/>
    <FORM/>
</CRUD>
```

#### Option 1: **Delegate**

Using a **delegate**, you can capture the reference for `GRID` component and call a `GRID` method from `FORM` through a delegate. Try [delegate sample at blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/ihjgq0iy).

Simplifying:

On `CRUD`:

```
<GRID @ref="mygrid" />
<FORM mydelegate="@( (s) => mygrid.setData(s) )" />

@code
{
    protected GRID mygrid;
}
```

On `GRID`:

```
<h1>@data</h1>

@code
{
    string data;

    public void setData(string value)
    {
        data = value;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

On `FORM`:

```
<input @bind-value=@somedata />
<button @onclick="@( () => mydelegate(somedata ?? "hi") )">press</button>

@code
{
    [Parameter] public Action<string> mydelegate {set; get;}
    string somedata;
}
```

#### Option 2: **Sharing the list**

Just share your list between components. You cal also subscribe `GRID` to `add` event list. More info at [How to handle add to list event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299920/how-to-handle-add-to-list-event). Of course, you can use also an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). Maybe you can avoid event, just adding to list and call `StateHasChanged` may be enough.

Remember you can share the list via parameters or [cascade parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#cascading-values-and-parameters).

```
<CRUD>
    <GRID data=@mylist />
    <FORM data=@mylist />
</CRUD>
```

#### Other options.

Do you have several more options like using a singleton via Dependency Injection, eventcallback, ... . I suggest to you to read [3 Ways to Communicate Between Components in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/) by [@Chris Sainty](https://twitter.com/chris_sainty)

Comment: I ended up using the delegate option it was perfekt for my application.

Comment: @fred,  Glad to hear.

Answer (score 4):

You should have posted a minimal repo with your question so that we can clearly see the issue you're facing.

However, generally speaking, there are a couple of ways to do this. In one of my answers in the Blazor section I have described three ways how to enable such scenario.

In this answer I'll suggest you to employ the App State Pattern, from which you can manage the state of your components, perform CRUD Actions related to the data in your components, refresh the components, etc.

An excellent sample created by Steve Anderson, which employ the App State Pattern is [FlightFinder](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor). This sample (Client project) defines a service named **AppState** which is injected to a number of components, and provide them with various functionalities. Please, inspect this class, and the components involved, and how they communicate with each other, and apply what you'll learn in your app. Don't hesitate to ask any question.

Note: If you are not acquainted with this sample, learn it thoroughly as this is an excellent way to learn Blazor.

See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886281/updating-other-blazor-components-from-elsewhere-in-the-application/56887009#56887009) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031183/blazor-grid-with-master-detail/54032042#54032042).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. This is probably also worth to be set as the correct answer, but I ended up using the delegate method Dani Herrera suggested. I had actually already found the FlightFinder. Probably from your Stackoverflow post. I think I was to stressed to go through and understand it at the time, but I will most definitely do it now.

Comment: @Fred, read the comments tothis question which sheds some light on the difference between using delegate (EventCallback, for instance) and the App State pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024328/data-binding-in-blazor-how-to-propagate-values-out-of-a-component