# Data binding in Blazor: How to propagate values out of a component?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, blazor

I have a fairly simple component, which looks like this:

```cs
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sampleText">Sample Text</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="sampleText"
               aria-describedby="sampleTextHelp"
               placeholder="Enter a text"
               @bind="@Value" />
        <small id="sampleTextHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a text to test the databinding</small>
    </div>
</form>
<p>You entered here: @Value</p>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I now add this to a page like this:

```cs
<MVVMTest Value="@_value" />
<p>
    You entered in MVVMTest:
    @_value
</p>

@functions {
    private string _value;
}
```

When I enter text in the input field, it is correctly updated at *You entered here:* but not propagated to *You entered in MVVMTest":

[image: MVVM not working]

What do I have to do to get this correctly propagated?

I could think of hooking up an `Action<string>` as a second `[Parameter]` which I fire inside the component when the text is changed, but it seems like a hackish and roundabout way. Is it how it has to be done, or is there a better way?

## Followup 1

The answer from Issac does not work because it stumbles over `@bind-value:oninput="@((e) => ValueChanged.Invoke(e.Value))"` with `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type`.

I had to do it in this roundabout way:

```cs
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sampleText">Sample Text</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="sampleText"
               aria-describedby="sampleTextHelp"
               placeholder="Enter a text"
               @bind="@Value" />
        <small id="sampleTextHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a text to test the databinding</small>
    </div>
</form>
<p>You entered here: @Value</p>

@code {

    private string _value;

    [Parameter]
    public string Value {
        get => _value;
        set {
            if(Equals(value, _value)) {
                return;
            }
            _value = value;
            OnValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

And using it like:

```cs
@inject HttpClient http
@page "/test"
<div class="top-row px-4">
    Test Page
</div>

<div class="content px-4">
    <MVVMTest Value="@_value" OnValueChanged="@(v => _value = v)" />
    <p>
        You entered in MVVMTest:
        @_value
    </p>
</div>

@functions {
    private string _value;
}
```

Not pretty, but it works. My "real" component is more complicated as a changed value triggers calls to the underlying ASP.net Core Service so I have to do elaborate detection who changes what to avoid infinite loops.

It would surely be better if Blazor supported XAML/WPF-like MVVM though...

## Followup 2

I came back to Issac's solution and with an extra cast, I got it working:

```cs
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sampleText">Sample Text</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="sampleText"
               aria-describedby="sampleTextHelp"
               placeholder="Enter a text"
               value="@Value"
               oninput="@((Func<ChangeEventArgs, Task>)(async e => await OnValueChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value as string)))" />
        <small id="sampleTextHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a text to test the databinding</small>
    </div>
</form>
<p>You entered here: @Value</p>

@code {

    private string _value;

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
<MVVMTest Value="@_value" OnValueChanged="@(v => _value = v)" />
<p>
    You entered in MVVMTest:
    @_value
</p>

@functions {
    private string _value;
}
```

This is already a known issue in Blazor. I tripped over this last week already, and I posted the workaround [in the VS developer forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/606560/intellisense-incorectly-reports-an-error-when-usin.html) as well.

Comment: Please be aware that using EventCallback raises StateHasChanged() in the parent component, which will then trigger rendering of all of the parent's children, so unless you want every component re-rendering on every keystroke or data change - maybe consider your architecture - look into the ShouldRender() override and implement code that ensures each component only renders when it needs to, or consider using a state management pattern that doesn't rely on the UI to propagate state changes.

Comment: This is also a good point. Is it also possible to just re-render a single component? Then, instead of `EventCallback` I could use `Action` or `Func` and have the component to decide when to re-render itself.

Comment: Yes, if you use Action/Func instead of EventCallback, then the parent can decide whether to call StateHasChanged, but if it does, you will still trigger re-rendering of all children. That's where state management outside of the UI shines - whichever method you choose, the component should be able to "register" itself to be notified when the data changes so it can call StateHasChanged itself.

Comment: That could be as simple as a simple State service in DI that has Actions/Events that it fires when data changes or it can get as complex as you like using any of the state management libraries out there. Or you can use ShouldRender() to as a passive way of opting out of re-rendering. On small personal projects I find a State service that implements events the simplest.

Comment: Wait a minute! You mentioned about avoiding infinite loops. I stumbled upon that exact problem. Simple case: I just pass input value one level up from checkbox to parent element. This causes infinite loop and crash. I had similar element, when I read value in JS and I have a flag preventing the loop, because I know the call from JS is the only case I should invoke `ValueChanged`. Now I don't have this distinction, so how do I implement infinite loop prevention?

Comment: What's more, Blazor has bug called a feature, that it tries re-initialize a component calling all its parameter setters if ANY event callback is called, even if it has no visible or other state changing effect. THIS is what causes infinite loops and unexpected crashes. I took me hundreds of hours to diagnose and workaround and causing problems even now. I posted that issue on Blazor's GIT, but they just said it's a feature, and basically - the workarounds are here to stay.

Comment: Is that `_value == value` check? If so, I just added it to my code and it worked, infinite loops just stopped to occur. I'm guessing invoking `ValueChanged` causes the setter to set the same value again and again. This is a clumsy workaround, but well, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an EventCallback parameter to do that:

```cs
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

read the section [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding)/Component parameters